# Java-Inheritance and polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance

Suppose there are two classes Circle and Cylinder.Circle is a super class of Cylinder class.In Circle class

```
getArea()
```

calculates the area of the Circle object and in the Cylinder class this method is overridden by defining it to calculate of the total surface area of the Cylinder object.
Now I do something like this:-

```
Circle c = new Cylinder(5.0);
```

I can invoke all the methods defined in Circle class but not those defined in Cylinder class.
But when I invoke

```
getArea()
```

overridden version of **getArea()** is invoked but not the one in Circle class.

**I don't understand why overridden version is invoked instead of the original version.**

Comment: That is the exact definition of polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why overridden version is invoked instead of the
>   original version.

When you are extending a SuperClass you do inherit the properties and the methods of the superclass, but if you Override those methods in your subclass, the methods in the subclass are invoked when the object is of the subClass.

Relate it with an day-to-day example:

```
class Developer{
    public writeCode{
         System.out.println("Supervisor will write the code here");
    }
}

class JrDeveloper extends Developer{
    @Override
    public writeCode{
         System.out.println("Jr.Developer will write code");
    }
}

class Test{

     public static void main(){
     Developer dev = new JrDeveloper();
     dev.writeCode();         // Do you really expect the Developer to write 
                              // the code or the Jr.Developer?
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Circle c` means that what you see from `c` is a `Circle` and that exactly defines how you can manipulate the object. It is a kind of a *view* of an object. Now when you call `getArea()` as it is defined in the `Circle` type the compiler lets you write the sentence, but the runtime dynamically deduces which is the right method to call. As the object referenced by `c` is a `Cylinder` then the `getArea()` method of it is called.

This is polymorphism : you cannot tell just by reading `c.getArea()` which is the *real* method that will be called.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of method to invoke is decided at runtime, based on the dynamic type of the object. In your case that is a cylinder (not a circle), so the version of `getArea()` on `Cylinder` will be invoked.

This is by design, and exactly how polymorphism is supposed to work. When used properly this allows very flexible and powerful behaviour, and grants the ability to code in an extensible way with minimal to no duplication of code. There should be no reason why you want the `getArea()` method on the superclass called instead, if there is then in all likelihood you haven't fulilled the "is-a" relationship properly when you created the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses what's known as [late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding). This means when you call a method on an instance, the instance itself determines which method to call.

Since you're calling on an instance of `Cylinder`, even though you're using a reference of its parents class, it uses the `Cylinder` method.

Languages like C++ provide the options to perform either late or early binding through use of the `virtual` keyword, java however does not.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the distinction between the type of the *reference* and the type of the *object*.

When you say

```
Circle c = new Cylinder(5.0);
```

the reference is `c` of type `Circle`, but the object is of type `Cylinder`. So when you call `c.getArea()`, you are looking at it from the `Circle` API/interface/perspective, but you are calling `getArea` on a `Cylinder` object. So that's why you are getting `Cylinder`'s implementation.

This means now that the rest of the code "just knows" that the object reference is a `Circle`.  So anyone who uses this code doesn't have to care if he is dealing with a `Circle` or a `Cylinder`, and if you add more classes that inherit from `Circle`, then he still doesn't care. Everything is just a `Circle` to him.

It gets a little tricky though when you add `getVolume()` to `Cylinder`. The reference type `c` is still `Circle`, so attempting to call `c.getVolume()` won't compile. Sure `Cylinder` has that method, but the reference type does not. So it won't work.

So just try to keep in mind the distinction between reference type and object type. Polymorphism means I can refer to many classes of objects through one kind of reference--sort of like how I can just use a play button on a tape recorder, a Kindle, a BluRay player, and so on and know exactly what it does.

That's pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand because you've got your inheritance backwards. One good reason to use inheritance is when you have a class you use everywhere, but in some cases you want to tweak it so you have an instance that behaves just a bit different.  This seems to be what you want here, because you're declaring your Cylinder as a Circle and using it as that.

If you start with a Cylinder and subclass it to get a Circle, everything makes much more sense.  A Cylinder is a lot more than a Circle, but a Circle is just a Cylinder that's been squashed flat.  If we ignore the fact that we could get the same effect with a Cylinder with a height of zero--and it *will* calculate values more efficiently--a Circle that extends Cylinder can be a very nice substitue for a Cylinder.  And now you get the right method when you call `getArea`.

There's a lot of good answers here about polymorphism.  But I've found in practice there's a strong tendency to get subclasses and superclasses reversed.  With subclassing, you're not trying to create a taxonomy, you're trying to refine existing behaviour (usually--there are other reasons to subclass).  I find it best to think about whether my proposed subclass might better be a superclass.  It usually doesn't, but the process stretches my brain a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is exactly that: dynamic binding at runtime. This means that your variable references the instance object you created with new but is from type of your declaration.

With polymorphism you can "normalize" different objects behavior or "devide" aquivalent  objects into different behaviors. Example with interface:

```
interface Animal {
  public void cry();
}

class Dog implements Animal{
  public void cry(){
    System.out.println("Wuff");
  }
}

class Cat implements Animal{
  public void cry(){
    System.out.println("Miau");
  }
}

Animal a1 = new Dog();
a1.cry();  // prints "Wuff"

Animal a2 = new Cat();
a2.cry();  // prints "Miau"
```